# Selecting html element tag(?) name selenium python

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am writing a function in python3 using selenium that will click a link given that it matches a provided text, but having trouble figuring out how to do so. The html is as follows:

`<a class="name-link" href="/colors/thisOne" </a>`

```
Yellow
```

I do know how to select the class name `"find_element_by_class_name("name-link")` but how would I also include the text `Yellow` as an option as well, so that my if statement would be like:

```
if 'Yellow' == (variable):
    .click()
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please Keep the complete <a> tag !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this one might help you solve the issue

```
find_element_by_link_text('Yellow')
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thank you! I guess I haven't fully understood the find_ methods yet. `link_text` works perfectly.

Comment: Happens Sometimes... Cheers !! :)